# How to close browser(ChromeDriver) on time using Python

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I made a Python program that opens my Youtube playlist using Selenium and I want to close that browser when all video is watched.
(I tried using `time.sleep()` but the problem is Youtube ads).
So, is there any way I can close my browser automatically when all video is watched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the video is finished `//div[@class='ytp-autonav-endscreen-button-container']` element appears so you can wait until this element appearing and then close the driver.
You can also simply locate it by the class name `'ytp-autonav-endscreen-button-container'` or other buttons / elements inside it.
So after staring the video use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ytp-autonav-endscreen-button-container')))
```

where `delay` is time that will be enough to the video to finish.
Lear more about webdriver explicit wait conditions [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Don't forget to add the essential imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: it doesn't wait for button it will directly give error

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: after this so i use click on that id

Comment: Yes, once `WebDriverWait` finished the element is presented on the page. In case of timeout exception will be thrown.

Comment: it is showing error webdriverwait is not defined

Comment: Sure, you need to add the imports. Answer is updated.

Comment: bro it doesn't wait it directly shutdowns

Comment: I see, sorry. Use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`. i updated the answer

Comment: Now I recognized that you are asking about a playlist, not a single video...

Comment: i doesn't matter i am testing it on single video

Comment: for single video try `ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-button ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-play-button` class name or `//a[@class='ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-button ytp-autonav-endscreen-upnext-play-button']` xpath instead

Comment: @GlossyPower Start from simple tasks. At least try `from selenium import webdriver` and check if site opens with `get`.

Comment: everything is fine until video ends

Comment: there is common error that name 'By' is not defined

Comment: I added that import too now

Comment: What exactly happens now?

Comment: Leave it im going to download all song and going to play with os

Comment: This suggestion also partially answers the question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make in in steps.

**First step:**

Wait for the last video in playlist:

By text:

```
last_video = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#secondary .index-message.style-scope.ytd-playlist-panel-renderer:nth-child(1)").text == "10 /10"
```

Or by waiting for the last element in the playlist directly:

```
last_video = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#secondary #items>.style-scope.ytd-playlist-panel-renderer:last-of-type").get_attribute("selected")
```

**Second step:**

After the first condition is true, wait for this video to finish, with this locator (**Replay** button)

```
video_ends = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ytp-chrome-controls button[title=Replay]")
```

For this you'll need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And use it like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_in_seconds)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#secondary .index-message.style-scope.ytd-playlist-panel-renderer:nth-child(1)").text == "10 /10")))
```

Timeout will depend of the length of playlist.

It is not a quick task, nobody will agree to finish it for you here.

Comment: bro it says name 'By' is not defined

Comment: from selenium import webdriver